# Ansible - Skip task when at least one item fails in loop

Tags: shell, ansible, sqlplus

I am running few SQL scripts using sqlplus present. Before running I am getting all the list of sql files from that directory and storing it in `sql_out` as shown below.

The problem is if one of the sql script fails the rest of the sql scripts still executes. I want to skip the task completely if any one of the script fails. Is there any way to skip. I reckon we can use `with_items` but not sure how to implement. Any help?

```
  - name: "Get sql files from directory"
    shell: ls {{ directory }}/{{ scripts_path }}/*.sql
    register: sql_out
    tags:
     - sql

  - name: "Execute each SQL Scripts"
    script: sqlplus.sh {{ db_username }} {{ db_password }} {{ 
    connection_string }} {{ schema }} {{ item }} 
    delegate_to: localhost

    with_items: sql_out.stdout_lines
    tags:
     - sql
```

Comment: Please describe the exact scenario of what you want to achieve. Give examples. Describe in what way the scripts fail. And don't parse `ls`!

Comment: Besides, is the `tags` vital to the question? Does the `script` parameter require the line break you included? Is the first task intended to run on remote target(s) and the second one locally? Because that's what's in the code. What do you mean by "*not sure how to implement*"? Did you try to run the code you posted, or decided it's not worth trying and better get someone on StackOverflow to do it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible as of current Ansible version 2.3.

Task executor works in [such way](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py#L97) that it executes every loop iteration first and only then analyzes task/items results.

You should refactor your shell script to be able to receive scripts list as parameter and iterate them inside the script, not with Ansible. This will also give you significant speed boost.

Comment: I beg to differ, it's perfectly doable.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have modified my shell script and removed the iteration in Ansible

Answer (score 3):

<sup>As you have not provided details on what do you mean by "*skip task*", I actually post only a concept answer. In the current form, the scripts will be run sequentially and if one fails, the whole task will fail. If you want other scripts to be skipped, you need to add additional check.</sup>

Extract the script-running task to a separate file and include it in a `with_fileglob`-loop:

```
- include: runscript.yml
  with_fileglob: "{{ directory }}/{{ scripts_path }}/*.sql"
```

with `runscript.yml`:

```
- script: sqlplus.sh {{ db_username }} {{ db_password }} {{ connection_string }} {{ schema }} {{ item }}
```

Comment: I agree that it is doable, but do not agree that it is perfect. We both know that looped include is entirely dufferent to looped task. Also this adds another layer of complexity and slowliness.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Strategy parameter in Ansible. It will stop executing playbook as task fails. 
  'strategy: debug'

`- name: Install & Configure Test server
  gather_facts: True
  strategy: debug
  sudo: yes
  hosts: test-client
  vars:
    test_server_ip: xxx.xxx.xx.xx 
  roles:
  - { role: tools,                      tags: ['tools']}
  - { role: test-client,               tags: ['test-client']}`

Details can be found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_debugger.html). I am using ansible 2.2.1.0