# Ansible - check for task failure during looping task's execution

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I have a task that should run a list of SQL scripts. If there is an error during the execution of **ANY** of the scripts in the sequence, then the task should stop executing.

Given the following task, is there a way that it can modified it to see the register's stdout for the current iteration of the loop to check if `'ERROR'` is in the stdout?

```
- name: Build and run SQLPlus commands
  shell: 'echo @{{ item }} | {{ sqlplus }} {{ db_user }}/{{ db_pass }}@{{ environment }}'
  register: sh1
  with_items:
    - ["a.sql", "b.sql"]
#      failed_when: "'ERROR' in sh1.stdout_lines"
```

I was thinking something along the lines of the last commented line, but since `sh1` is a register variable from a looping task, the output from each SQL script resides within the *list* `results` of `sh1`; so I'm not sure how to access the specific stdout of the command that was just executed.

Comment: If the shell command returns non-zero exit code, the task will fail automatically. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: @helloV It's not the command that is erring, the command executes a SQL script using sqlplus and the output from sqlplus contains the word "ERROR" if the script didn't run correctly. I know the shell command is executing successfully because i get an exit code 0 after following up the sqlplus command with `echo $?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was thinking something along the lines of the last commented line,

Until now you were thinking correctly, so just uncomment the line:

```
- name: Build and run SQLPlus commands
  shell: 'echo @{{ item }} | {{ sqlplus }} {{ db_user }}/{{ db_pass }}@{{ environment }}'
  register: sh1
  with_items:
    - ["a.sql", "b.sql"]
  failed_when: "'ERROR' in sh1.stdout_lines"
```

> but since `sh1` is a register variable from a looping task, the output from each SQL script resides within the *list* `results` of `sh1`;

No. Within the task, the values in `sh1` dictionary are accessible in each iteration directly (without a list). The list `sh1.results` will be visible for subsequent tasks.

---

But the above won't break the execution of the whole loop, which is how Ansible was designed. So to realise the following...

> If there is an error during the execution of ANY of the scripts in the sequence, then the task should stop executing.

You can use a workaround: save the task to a separate file and iterate the `include` task (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780091/2947502)).

Comment: Thanks for the details, and especially for providing an example. I had an idea similar to looping over includes — looping over blocks. Sadly, it hasn't been implemented yet, and [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262) they suggested to do as you said so I suppose that's my best option.

Comment: According to the [Ansible Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse.html) there is no output for the dynamically included tasks: "Tasks which only exist inside a dynamic include will not show up in –list-tasks output." This only happens when I use a previously defined register variable for the `with_fileglob`. Changing it to `with_items` works and I can see the output for the tasks that have been included.

Comment: For those trying to use up-to-date practices, apparently the [include](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_module.html) module is deprecated, but [include_tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_tasks_module.html) isn't available until 2.4; so make sure you're using the right module.